# How can I bypass the https security certificate screen?

Tags: java, internet-explorer, selenium, testng

I have created some java classes that use testng and selenium frameworks. For the moment, when I execute the tests with Chrome/Firefox, they run smoothly.

However, when I execute those tests with Internet Explorer, the security certificate message is shown.

How can I bypass this screen and continue with the execution of my tests ? [Browser Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Taqd.png)

---

I used these two lines of code as well:

webDriver.get("javascript:document.getElementById('overridelink').click();");

or

webDriver.navigate().to("javascript:document.getElementById('overridelink').click();");

In either case, the link is not pressed.

I am using Internet Explorer 11.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://sqa.stackexchange.com/a/1932) helps.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can try to install self signed certificate.
   In Windows Internet Explorer, click Continue to this website (not recommended).

   - A red Address Bar and a certificate warning appear.
   - Click the Certificate Error button to open the information window.
   - Click View Certificates, and then click Install Certificate.
   - On the warning message that appears, click Yes to install the certificate.

If you are not satisfied or it did not help to solve the problem you have actually many ways how to obey the warning page or solving the problem. I am not sure which will help to fix your problem because you did not provide much information..... try for example this one:

2. Try to turn off  publishers and servers cert. revocation
   Launch Internet Explorer on a desktop computer.

   - Click Tools -> "Internet Options" window appears -> Advanced tab
   - Under "Security", uncheck the boxes "Check for publisher's revocation" and "Check for server certificate revocation.".

It should do the trick. If not, please try to provide more info.

Answer (score 0):

You can use desired capability class to overcome this. Please find the code below,

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver","IEDriverServer.exe");
WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(capabilities);
```

Comment: I have already used this capability type to make it work for Chrome and Firefox. Internet Explorer doesn't seem to be influenced by this.